# Minimum sum in an array with constraint

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am a newbie to the dynamic programming paradigm.. while trying to solve this question.......

> How to find minimum sum of the numbers in an given array such that at
>   least one of three consecutive elements are picked.

I do not understand how to divide this problem in to sub problems.

Comment: In the candidate set for the minimum sum.. there should be at least one number from any three consecutive numbers in the array.
For example.. consider array {3,2,7,10,9}
only {2} cannot be chosen because there is no element from last three consecutive elements 7,10,9 in the chosen set {2}.

Answer (score 0):

It is a linear dp with sub problems as follows: To find the minimum sum at position n , it will be the minimum of dp of n-1 ,n-2 and n-3 such that their last items are n-1, n-2 and n-3 respectively , so our base case will be dp[0] = arr[0], dp[1] = arr[1] and dp[2] = arr[2] while for i>=3 it will be  dp[i] = min(dp[i-1],min(dp[i-2],dp[i-3]))+arr[i] which gives us the correct answer. Here is a c++ implementation of same

https://bpaste.net/show/c18e79275830